# Firebase cloud function deploy occurs Error: There was an error deploying functions occurs

Tags: javascript, firebase

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions

//// The Firebase Admin SDK to access Firestore.
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();



exports.makeUppercase = functions.firestore.document('/users')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {
      // Grab the current value of what was written to Firestore.
        functions.logger.log("Yahoo!");
    });
```

This is the index.js from functions folder, and if I enter function deploy, Error: There was an error deploying functions occurs. I don't know where is the error, and I think I make a mistake, but I cannot find it. I infer that the country problem(I set the firebase project to asia-northeast3) is the main issue, but It is just the prediction.

EDIT

```
package.json

{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^10.0.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.18.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

If I enter firebase functions:log, firebase functions:log
2022-10-10T13:27:50.775663Z I undefined: {"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog","authenticationInfo":{"principalEmail": ~~~
appears.

Comment: Can you share your `package.json` file

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Here is My package.json!

Comment: To deploy to the recommended Node.js 14 runtime environment, your project must be on the Blaze pricing plan. If you are on spark plan, the emulator will work but upload will fail.

Comment: @mcy Actually, I alreay update to Blaze! Is there any problem with code?

Comment: The code is nearly ok: just add a return at the end (`exports.makeUppercase = functions.firestore.document('/users').onCreate((snap, context) => {functions.logger.log("Yahoo!"); return null;});`). Of course as such the CF does do anything apart logging a msg...

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Thanks, but it still doesn't work... Do I need to set the region before deploying like fucntions.~~(asia-northeast3).~~?

Comment: The problem is not coming from he code. Even without the addition of `return null;` it should deploy. But I cannot tell you, with the shared elements, where is the problem.